# Post Data with AngularJS into JSON directly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm still new in AngularJS, so far I've succeeded to fetch data from JSON in my Controller

```
var testAppApp = angular.module('testAppApp', []);
testAppApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('data/data.json')
        .then(function(takeprocess) {
            $scope.customers = takeprocess.data.records;
        });
});
```

here my JSON format

```
{ 
"records": [
{
  "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
  "City": "Berlin",
  "Country": "Germany"
},
{
  "Name": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
  "City": "México D.F.",
  "Country": "Mexico"
},
............
}
```

My index.html

```
<div ng-controller="SimpleController">
Search <input type="text" ng-model="filter.name" /> 
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:'No'">
{{$index +1}} - {{cust.Name}} - {{cust.City}} - {{cust.Country}}</li>
</ul> 
Adding New Customer <br/>
Name: <br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="Name" /><br/>
City: <br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="City" /><br/>
Country: <br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="Country" /><br/> 
<button ng-click="addCustomer(Name, City, Country)">Add Customer</button>
</div>
```

[Here my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwGQN.png)

I want create function addCustomer to post data, and (maybe) store the data into JSON, but I don't know how create the function... in many ways, some people talk angularJS is Front End framework, it can't store data to JSON directly. Please suggest me to make a point, In my case I want put new data into list and permanent

Comment: what do you mean by store JSON directly ? with angular you can send the JSON you create to the backend, but the backend is not part of angular - it can be created with many languages. AngularJS is frontend only

Comment: Technically, you could do this if your web server supports [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), but that opens up a huge security hole and most hosting companies won't open those up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I save a file on an http server using just http requests and javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921558/how-can-i-save-a-file-on-an-http-server-using-just-http-requests-and-javascript)

Comment: Thanks all for your help, my question isn't necessary technically, but I'm confused what should I do, it seems I should combine my angularJS with other back end language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "store the data into JSON" do you mean put it into the data.json file directly?

If yes, Javascript is a front end language and doesn't have access to the file system that hosts it. The solution would be to run a back end language like Go, Node.JS or PHP to accept a post request and write that data to your data.json.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it make a point to me. I should make hybrid way, like combine angularJS with PHP or any.

Comment: Exactly this is what all web apps do to edit data on the machine that is hosting it or a database on the server that is hosting it.